# How can I clear the cached settings for Mail?

Tags: release-loki, applications, pantheon-mail

Mail is holding on to cached account settings. So now no matter how many times I delete the email account from the Systems Setting online account the SMTP settings wont clear when I re-enter the account.

Also in the Mail app the Accounts settings panel is too long(vertically) so you can't see the apply/OK, cancel buttons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can see the content in the Pantheon Mail folder with:

```
ls .local/share/pantheon-mail/
```

You going to see a folder with the names of your e-mail accounts, something like my_name@example.com, so you can delete that folder with:

```
rm -rf .local/share/pantheon-mail/my_name@example.com
```

Of course you can delete completely the folder of Pantheon Mail:

```
rm -rf .local/share/pantheon-mail/
```

And that is all, i suppose that is what you wanna to do.

Comment: Thanks!! That worked. For those having the same issue and don't want to use the command like simply open up your file manager then Ctrl+H. This will show you your hidden files and directories.

 Once there go to .local/share/pantheon-mail and remove the email accounts. If you want to delete and clear the mail app cache simply delete the pantheon-mail directory.